# Regex parser implementing dot, star and question mark

Tags: java, regex, reinventing-the-wheel

> Regex parser which follows the following rule
>
> 1. `.` (dot) means a any single character match
> 2. `*` (star) means 0 or more character match
> 3. `?` (question) means previous char is an option i.e `colou?r` matches `color` and `colour`.

A large feedback has been taken from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35552/regex-parser-request-for-review-and-optimization).

I'm looking for code review, optimizations, best practices.  I also still get confused with complexity.  Let's say regex string has length of `m` and string has length of `n`.  Then it appears the complexity would be `O(n! * (n-1)! * ... (n-m)!)`

```
public final class Regex {

    private Regex() {};

    private static enum Wildcards {
        STAR('*'), DOT('.'), QUESTION('?');

        private final char wildCard;

        Wildcards (char wildCard) {
            this.wildCard = wildCard; 
        }

        public char getWildCard() {
            return this.wildCard;
        }
    }


    /**
     * The index of first non-star character following first occurence of star
     * eg: if regex is a**b, then index is startIndex is 1 and return value is 3 (index of b)
     * 
     * @param regex          : the regex string.
     * @param firstStarIndex : index of the first occurene of * after a non *, eg: a**b, then starIndex would be 1
     * @return               : the index of first non-star character following first occurence of star
     */
    private static final int getNonWildCardIndex(String regex, int firstQuestionIndex, Wildcards foo) {
        for (int k = firstQuestionIndex; k < regex.length(); k++) {
            if (regex.charAt(k) != foo.getWildCard()) {
                return k;
            }
        }
        return regex.length();
    }

    /**
     * A valid wildcard tail is a tail of ?' s and *'s.
     * Its a tail which matches 0 characters
     * 
     * @param regex         The input regex
     * @param index         The index from which the wild card check must be initiated.
     * @return  true is the resulting wildcard matches empty string.
     */
    private static final boolean validWildCardTail(String regex, int index) {
        assert regex != null;

        for (int i = index; i < regex.length(); i++) {
            if (regex.charAt(i) !=  Wildcards.QUESTION.getWildCard() && 
                    regex.charAt(i) !=  Wildcards.STAR.getWildCard()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if we have scanned the entire string for regex match.
     * If not, it means some characters from strPos in the input string do not match regex.
     * 
     * @param str       The input string.
     * @param strPos    The current string index
     * @return  true if entire string has been scanned for regex match.
     */
    private static final boolean endOfStringCheck(String str, int strPos) {
        return str.length() == strPos;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the regex matches matches the empty string. At this point input string has been traversed.
     * Only the regex needs to be travelled to.
     * 
     * @param regex       The input regex
     * @param regexPos    The current regex index.
     * @return  true if regex matches the input string
     */
    private static final boolean endOfRegexCheck (String regex, int regexPos) {        
        if (regexPos == regex.length()) return true;

        // example: regex: "colou?",  string: "colou"
        if (regex.charAt(regexPos) == Wildcards.QUESTION.getWildCard() || 
                // example: regex: "colou?", string: "colo" 
                (regexPos < (regex.length() - 1)) && regex.charAt(regexPos + 1) == Wildcards.QUESTION.getWildCard() || 
                        // example: regex: "colo*",  string: "colour"
                    regex.charAt(regexPos) == Wildcards.STAR.getWildCard()) {

            // regex : colou?**.***, string : colou
            // check the  `regexPos + 1 argument`, its very sensible. regixPos is already checked. thus we start check from the next position.
            return validWildCardTail(regex, regexPos + 1);
        } else {
            return false; 
        }
    }

    private static final boolean matcher(String regex, int regexPos, String str, int strPos) {
        assert regexPos >= 0 && regexPos <= regex.length();
        assert strPos >= 0 && strPos <= str.length(); // it should break when its == strPos, > strpos is an impossible condition.

        while ((regexPos < regex.length() && strPos < str.length())) {

            if (regex.charAt(regexPos) == str.charAt(strPos) || regex.charAt(regexPos) == Wildcards.DOT.getWildCard()) {
                regexPos++; 
                strPos++;
            } 
            /*
             *  nested if else is better than non-nested.
             *  http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~pjbk/pathways/cpp1/node99.html
             */
            else if (regex.charAt(regexPos) == Wildcards.STAR.getWildCard()) {
                int nextNonStarIndex = getNonWildCardIndex(regex, regexPos,  Wildcards.STAR);

                /*
                 * For a case where regex and string, both have not yet reached the last char but regex is all *'s till end.
                 * Eg:  Regext abc*** && String is abcxyz
                 */
                if (nextNonStarIndex == regex.length()) return true;

                while (strPos < str.length()) {
                    if (matcher(regex, nextNonStarIndex, str, strPos)) return true;
                    strPos = strPos + 1;
                }

                return false;
            } else {
                // regex  : colou?r
                // string : colour 
                if (regex.charAt(regexPos) == Wildcards.QUESTION.getWildCard()) {
                    return matcher(regex, getNonWildCardIndex(regex, regexPos,  Wildcards.QUESTION), str, strPos);
                }

                // regex: colou?r
                // regex: color
                if (regexPos < (regex.length() - 1) && regex.charAt(regexPos + 1) ==  Wildcards.QUESTION.getWildCard()) {
                    return matcher(regex, getNonWildCardIndex(regex, regexPos + 1,  Wildcards.QUESTION), str, strPos);
                }

                return false;
            }
        }

        return endOfStringCheck(str, strPos) && endOfRegexCheck(regex, regexPos);
    }


    /**
     * Matches the regex with the string with the following rules.
     *  *  means 0 or more number of any char matches
     *  .  means just a single any char match.
     *  ?  means the immediate preceding character can exist or not. eg: colour? matches color and colour
     * 
     * @param regex  : The regex to match the string again
     * @param str    : The string to be matched.
     * @return       : true / false
     */
    public static final boolean matches(String regex, String str) {
        return matcher(regex, 0, str, 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches("colou?**rs", "colours"));
        Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches("colou?**rs", "colors"));

        Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches("colou**?rs", "colours"));
        // Assert.assertTrue(RegexToy.matches("colou**?rs", "colors")); <---- exlusive case.

        Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches("colou?**r", "colour"));
        Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches("colou?**r", "color"));

        Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches("colou?*", "colou"));
        Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches("colou?*", "colo"));

        Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches("colou?r", "colour"));
        Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches("colou?r", "color"));

        Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches("colou?*?r", "colour"));
        Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches("colou?*?r", "color"));

        // Success cases
        Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches("", ""));
        Assert.assertTrue((Regex.matches("***", "")));

        String[] regexList = { "abc****", "abc", "a*b*c", "****abc", "**a**b**c****", "abc*" };
        String str1 = "abc";

        for (String regex : regexList) {
            Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches(regex, str1));
        }

        String regex = "abc****";
        String[] strList1 = { "abcxyz", "abcx", "abc" };
        for (String str : strList1) {
            Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches(regex, str));
        }

        regex = "***abc";
        String[] strList2 = { "xyzabc", "xabc", "abc" };
        for (String str : strList2) {
            Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches(regex, str));
        }

        Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches("a.c", "abc"));
        Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches("a*.*c", "abc"));


        Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches("a*.b.*c", "axxbxxbxxc"));

        // Fail cases.
        Assert.assertFalse(Regex.matches("abc", "abcd"));
        Assert.assertFalse(Regex.matches("*a", "abcd"));
        Assert.assertFalse(Regex.matches("a", ""));
        Assert.assertFalse(Regex.matches(".a*c", "abc"));
        Assert.assertFalse(Regex.matches("a.*b", "abc"));
        Assert.assertFalse(Regex.matches("..", "abc"));
        Assert.assertFalse(Regex.matches("", "abc"));

        // exceptions
        try {
            Regex.matches(null, "abc");
            Assert.fail();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }

        try {
            Regex.matches("abc", null);
            Assert.fail();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is rather nice, but the algorithm is fundamentally flawed. Consider these test cases, which you currently fail:

```
// The empty string is a substring of any string
Assert.assertTrue(Regex.matches("", "abc"));

// Because you check for direct character equivalence before metacharacters,
// a string containing regex metacharacters will falsely pass
Assert.assertFalse(Regex.matches("a*b", "a*b"));

// We should reject malformed regexes
try {
    Regex.matches("***", "");
    Assert.fail();
} catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
}
```

Furthermore, your regex dialect is unable to match all regular languages: It is possible that a *group* of characters (and not just a single character) is repeated:

```
S := A
A := "ab" A
A := ""
```

This grammar can produce the strings `""`, `"ab"`, `"abab"` etc. It is matched by the regular expression `(ab)*`. However, you do not offer such groupings. Other features that are lacking and are generally expected of regexes:

- A `+` quantifier
- alternatives `|` (this is strictly required)
- character classes `[a-z]` (only needed in real-life applications, not in theoretical settings)
- Escape sequences like `\*` to match a literal `*`, instead of `*` being a metacharacter.

Don't *interpret* the regex character by character. This is buggy, and – as shown above – prone to all kinds of failures<sup>(1)</sup>. Instead, write a proper *parser* and compile the regex to some intermediate representation. For example, the regex `(ab|c)*` might be equivalent to this data structure:

```
new Regex.Star(new Regex.Alternative(new Regex.Constant("ab"),
                                     new Regex.Constant("c")))
```

Given such a data structure, writing a backtracking regex engine is very easy. Of course, regular expressions can also be translated to a state machine, which is a bit more complicated – but the first step is to make it work correctly, before you try any clever optimizations.

---

1. Especially, regular expressions themselves do not follow a regular grammar.

Comment: Seems to me that: `matches("a*b", "a*b")` should yield true. The pattern says: `"a" optionally followed by arbitrary characters, followed by "b"`. The target of `a*b` seems to fit the perfectly well.

Comment: @JerryCoffin in a [*shell glob pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), yes. In a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), `*` (the [Kleene Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star)) is a *repetition operator* that repeats the previous atom (character or group) zero or more times. So `a*b` means any number of `a`s followed by a single `b`.

Comment: He's pretty clearly described the goal at the beginning of the question, and it says: "* (star) means 0 or more character match". Seems to me you've concentrated a lot on the "regex" part, and nearly ignored the more specific description of the code's intent.