# Another regex subset matcher

Tags: c++, c, regex

After reading @JavaDeveloper's [recent question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/43579/489), I was inspired<sup>1</sup> to try my hand at writing code to accomplish the same task.

The "rules" for this code (i.e., its intent) is to match a subset of regular expressions, defined as follows:

> 1. `.` (dot) means a any single character match
> 2. `*` (star) means 0 or more character match
> 3. `?` (question) means previous char is an option i.e `colou?r` matches `color` and `colour`.

Just to be clear: I'm well aware that this is *not* how regular expressions are normally defined, and that the fundamental capability of this subset is exactly that--a subset of what full regexes can recognize/match.

As an aside: although tagging a question with both C and C++ is normally a mistake, I believe in this case it's justified. In particular, the `match` function is at least intended to be work as either C or C++. The test rig (enabled by defining `TEST` when compiling) uses features to specific to C++, but `match` itself should not.

Without further ado, my attempt at implementing this functionality:

```
#include <string.h>
#ifndef __cplusplus
#include <stdbool.h>
#endif

bool match(char const *needle, char const *haystack) {
    for (; *needle!='\0'; ++needle) {
        switch (*needle) {
        case '.': ++haystack;
        case '?': break;
        case '*': {
            size_t max = strlen(needle);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < max; i++)
                if (match(needle + 1, haystack + i))
                    return true;
            return false;
        }
        default:
            if (*haystack == *needle) 
                ++haystack;
            else if (needle[1] != '?')
                return false;
        }
    }
    return *haystack == '\0';
}

#ifdef TEST
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template<class F> 
void assertTrue(F f, char const *needle, char const *hay_stack) {
    static const std::string names [] = { "Failure", "Success" };
    std::cout << names[f(needle, hay_stack)];
    std::cout << " for: " << needle << "->" << hay_stack << "\n";
}

template<class F>
void assertFalse(F f, char const *needle, char const *hay_stack) {
    static const std::string names [] = { "Success", "Failure" };
    std::cout << names[f(needle, hay_stack)];
    std::cout << " for: " << needle << "->" << hay_stack << "\n";
}

int main(){
    assertTrue(match,"colou?**rs", "colours");
    assertTrue(match,"colou?**rs", "colors");

    assertTrue(match,"colou**?rs", "colours");
    // assertTrue(RegexToy.match,"colou**?rs", "colors"); <---- exlusive case.

    assertTrue(match,"colou?**r", "colour");
    assertTrue(match,"colou?**r", "color");

    assertTrue(match,"colou?*", "colou");
    assertTrue(match,"colou?*", "colo");

    assertTrue(match,"colou?r", "colour");
    assertTrue(match,"colou?r", "color");

    assertTrue(match,"colou?*?r", "colour");
    assertTrue(match,"colou?*?r", "color");

    // Success cases
    assertTrue(match,"", "");
    assertTrue(match, "***", "");

    std::vector<char const *> regexList { "abc****", "abc", "a*b*c", "****abc", "**a**b**c****", "abc*" };
    char const *str1 = "abc";

    for (auto regex : regexList) 
        assertTrue(match,regex, str1);

    char const *regex = "abc****";
    std::vector<char const *> strList1 { "abcxyz", "abcx", "abc" };
    for (auto str : strList1) 
        assertTrue(match,regex, str);

    regex = "***abc";
    std::vector<char const *> strList2 { "xyzabc", "xabc", "abc" };
    for (auto str : strList2) 
        assertTrue(match, regex, str);  

    assertTrue(match, "a.c", "abc");
    assertTrue(match, "a*.*c", "abc");


    assertTrue(match,"a*.b.*c", "axxbxxbxxc");

    // Fail cases.
    assertFalse(match,"abc", "abcd");
    assertFalse(match,"*a", "abcd");
    assertFalse(match,"a", "");
    assertFalse(match,".a*c", "abc");
    assertFalse(match,"a.*b", "abc");
    assertFalse(match,"..", "abc");
    assertFalse(match,"", "abc");
}
#endif
```

---

1. Along with stealing the idea from @JavaDeveloper, I also stole his test rig, with only minor editing. I hope that's not a problem (I think my making attribution to him clear mans it falls within SE's licensing).

Comment: This is actually a complete wildcards grammar, I think.

Comment: @AJMansfield: It is much closer to globbing than normal regexes, but I decided to keep the same rules as the previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex flavour is non-standard, as you noted.  Just to be clear, `?` acts as a zero-or-one-of-the-previous-character modifier, while `*` acts more like a shell glob.

You have an access-past-the-end-of-string error when testing for glob matches in a test such as this:

```
assertFalse(match, "**a", "b");
```

The for-loop speculatively matches `max` substrings of the `haystack`, where `max` is based on the length of the `needle`.  If the matches don't succeed, you could easily walk past the end of the haystack.

Your `switch` block is fragile: the `'.'` case relies on the `break` of the following `'?'` case.  That's a bit too clever and dangerous for my taste, and a warning comment would be useful.

Comment: Good point--I'd intended `strlen(haystack)`, but that's not quite right either. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The output of your unit tests is unintuitive.  For example,

> ```
> Success for: ..->abc
> ```

Huh?  That should not match.  Oh, it turns out that it was an `assertFalse()`.  It would have been clearer to print

```
[PASS] Match ..->abc returns false
```